# High chart animation lag after it moves from viewport

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm drawing chart and I see that after the graph crosses the viewport the drawing is not smooth and the drawing becomes inconsistent with a lag.

```
chart.series[0].addPoint([x,getRandomInt(40, 95)], true, shiftFlag);
chart.series[1].addPoint([x,getRandomInt(40, 95)], true, shiftFlag);
chart.series[2].addPoint([x,getRandomInt(40, 95)], true, shiftFlag);
```

Fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bRp6h/38/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `redraw` once for every point when you add them, which uses extra resources.

> addPoint(options [, redraw] [, shift] [, animation])

What you should instead do is to explicitly call [`chart.redraw()`](https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Chart#redraw) which redraws the chart once, instead of the 3 times, like this :

```
chart.series[0].addPoint([x,getRandomInt(40, 95)], false, shiftFlag);
chart.series[1].addPoint([x,getRandomInt(40, 95)], false, shiftFlag);
chart.series[2].addPoint([x,getRandomInt(40, 95)], false, shiftFlag);
chart.redraw();
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/bRp6h/42/

**API on series.addPoint:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Series#addPoint